# OpenCV python slow performance in Win10

Tags: python, linux, opencv, user-interface

I have a simple code that works much slower in Win10, and fast as hell in Linux.
The code returns the sum of all pixel intensity for all frames in video file.
Unfortunately, I must run it in Win10, so I'd like to know the reason for such a slowdown.
I have tried different CPUs, but that's not the case.

In Win10 I can process tested video file in 25 seconds.
[image]

In Linux, it takes only 1.5 seconds
[image]

What is the reason for such behavior? Can I speed up this somehow in Win10?

```
import sys
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

start = time.time()

file_name = sys.argv[1]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)
success, image = cap.read()
count = 0

# width = int(cap.get(3)) #.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # float `width`
# height = int(cap.get(4)) #.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float `height`

fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
N_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
width = int(cap.get(3))  # float `width`
height = int(cap.get(4))  # float `height`
# print(width, height)
w = 70
print(f"FPS = {fps}, N_frames = {N_frames}, WxH={width}x{height}")

# print(width, height)

with open("res_vid.txt", "w") as res:
    pbar = tqdm(total=N_frames)
    while success:
        count += 1
       
        res.write(f"{count:5d}  {gray_img.sum():10d}\n")

        pbar.update(1)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        success, image = cap.read()
    pbar.close()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

UPDATE:

win10 getBuildInformation()

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.9.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.9.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-12-31T11:21:12Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.24.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (8 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (36 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24247.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    java world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.3)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2021.11.0 [2021.11.0]
           at:                   D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2021.11.0)
              at:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
    Flatbuffers:                 builtin/3rdparty (23.5.9)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/python.exe (ver 3.7.9)
    Libraries:                   C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/libs/python37.lib (ver 3.7.9)
    numpy:                       C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.7.9\\x64\\python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    Java:                        YES (ver 1.8.0.392)
    JNI:                         C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.392-8/x64/include C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.392-8/x64/include/win32 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.392-8/x64/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Linux getBuildInformation()

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.9.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.9.0-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-12-31T11:18:53Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-1053-azure x86_64
    CMake:                       3.28.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (8 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (36 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/c++  (ver 10.2.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          /lib64/libopenblas.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /usr/local/lib/libpng.so /lib64/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:                           QT5
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0 )
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/local/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.40)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (59.37.100)
      avformat:                  YES (59.27.100)
      avutil:                    YES (57.28.100)
      swscale:                   YES (6.7.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2021.10.0 [2021.10.0]
           at:                   /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2021.10.0)
              at:                /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    VA:                          NO
    Lapack:                      YES (/lib64/libopenblas.so)
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
    Flatbuffers:                 builtin/3rdparty (23.5.9)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python3.7 (ver 3.7.17)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.7m.a (ver 3.7.17)
    numpy:                       /home/ci/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            /opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python3.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    Java:                        NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-install
```

Comment: some functions/modules used by opencv vary upon the operating system, this can greatly affect your perfomance

Comment: The two variants running on equivalent hardware? Same version of OpenCV? Built with same options (`getBuildInformation()`) especially regarding instruction sets? Same VideoIO backend? What does a profiler tell you?

Comment: @DanMašek  I updated the post with getBuildInformation() info

Comment: Different disk I/O.  Is everything processed and stored in RAM?

Comment: Video file has 800 Kb size this is not the reason. And Yes I think it is processed in RAM

Comment: At this point it would be really good to know where it's spending most of the time. Grab some decent line-level profiler that can also properly deal with native libraries like OpenCV and numpy (Scalene seems to be a nice one that runs on both platforms), and use it to find the bottleneck. That's the most important thing to do, because otherwise we're just guessing. | Also, I just realized, `gray_img.sum()` is a call to Numpy, not OpenCV. How do the versions of Numpy compare between those who configurations? (That's yet another complication, since I think that can use multiple math "backends")

Comment: I think I see the problem now. You have a call to `cv2.waitKey(10)` in your loop body. That means that each iteration, at least 10ms should be spent in that function call, giving us an upper bound at 100 iterations per second. On Windows, you get ~64, which makes sense, since the other code takes some time as well -- roughly 5-6ms it seems. On the other hand, on Linux you get ~1660 iterations per second, which should be impossible if `waitKey` actually waited as long as it should. So that definitely raises some alarms.

Comment: You're not displaying anything, so drop the `cv2.waitKey` call. You definitely don't need it for performance comparisons, on the contrary it adds unnecessary noise. In fact, drop the progress bar as well. Re-run the basic measurements, and then profile the new simplified code. Then it should be just two possible culprits -- either the video decoder, or the build of numpy you have.

Comment: Windows scheduler does 64 time slices per second (default). a Sleep() has that granularity. that's how you get more or less 64 fps. I agree that the linux situation is sketchy af. no-op (no-sleep) waitkey happens when there isn't even a window (even on Windows, so IDK why it would even sleep at all there).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After cv2.waitKey(10) was commented out, the process took 0.6 sec in Win10